# Can i build an app that edits the conatct list on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, contacts, appstore-approval

Hey everybody,
I want to create an app that handles some sort of recognition of another person in my area, and creates a new contact based on his info. regardless to how it is done, my question is more basic - can i, or maybe i should ask will Apple approve an application that edits the contact list in the IPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can edit the contact List from your application by using the address book API.

Cheers

Comment: Will Apple approve such application?

Comment: Yes of course,Apple has provided the Address Book API and its is a public API and there are various different methods to make changes in the Address book itself..So go ahead and code..

Comment: Please consider joining [the App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores) on Area 51. Questions about App Store approval are probably more appropriate there.

Answer (score 1):

The [AddressBook](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html) framework allows access to a centralized contacts database, called the Address Book database, that stores a user’s contacts.